# Count-if column between two list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, if-condition, count

I have 2 lists on one SharePoint site. One works as a query log (I used a custom list instead of issue tracking) and a second one is a master data list with a RAG status.

What I want to achieve is to have a count of open logs in a query log list (with a status different than "Closed" from column "Query Status") appearing in the master data list.

Common column between the two list is "Item Reg". In query log I can have a number of logs created for Item Reg: FR1982 and in master data list I can only have one item with Item Reg: FR1982.

I'd need this count of open logs appear in one of the columns in master data list and update automatically by a workflow each time a new log is created in query log list or status of existing log is changed in query log list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood you correct, but if you want to count the records with the same property in one list, create a workflow variable and then set this value to a column in this list (or another list).

Or you can use REST API to get the item counts if you are familiar with it.

See the references here:

[Workflow counts list items.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264622/workflow-counts-list-items)

[Getting count of items in a List using the Call Http Web Service Action.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ffc4efb5-29b5-4332-bb9f-31ba37e67153/getting-count-of-items-in-a-list-using-the-call-http-web-service-action?forum=sharepointcustomization)